# The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription

Tags: powershell, azure, deployment, automation, teamcity

Trying to script to automate deployement in Azure on VM created on Azure. Everything was just dandy yesterday. I did the setup and alI the services were deploying to their respective subscription.

There were also a number of Azure management certificates hanging around in my certificates area. I've cleared them all out since all but one were very old. I then re-imported the latest publish settings file hoping that by starting from the beginning, everything would be happy again.

And then I logged in today, ran one of my deployment and it said:

```
The server failed to authenticate the request. 
Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.
```

No problem, just use the handy-dandy add-azureaccount, it logs me back in, re-run the deployment and again it says:

```
Set-AzureService : ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the
request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this
subscription.
```

Does any one has any idea about how to get authenticate to server ?

All this automation I am doing on A VM created on Azure and installed Teamcity on VM.
When i try to run the scripts directly on VM Powershell it works fine
But the error occurs when i try to run the Teamcity configuration, It fails in PowerShell Build Step.

It though returns the subscriptions that are there on VM by the command 
**Get-AzureSubscription**

> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] SubscriptionId            : *******
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] SubscriptionName          : ****
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] Environment               : AzureCloud
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] SupportedModes            : AzureServiceManagement
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] DefaultAccount            : *******
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] Accounts                  : *******
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] IsDefault                 : True
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] IsCurrent                 : True
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] CurrentStorageAccountName : *******
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] TenantId                  :
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] SubscriptionId            : *******
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] SubscriptionName          : *******
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] Environment               : AzureCloud
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] SupportedModes            : AzureServiceManagement
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] DefaultAccount            : *******
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] Accounts                  : *******
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] IsDefault                 : False
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] IsCurrent                 : False
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] CurrentStorageAccountName : tarifficapi
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3] TenantId                  :
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3]
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3]
>
> [11:31:07][Step 3/3]
>
> [11:31:21][Step 3/3] Set-AzureService : ForbiddenError: The server failed to >authenticate the
>
> [11:31:21][Step 3/3] request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is >associated with this
>
> [11:31:21][Step 3/3] subscription.
>
> [11:31:21][Step 3/3] At line:1 char:1
>
> [11:31:21][Step 3/3] + Set-AzureService -ServiceName $service -Label 
>   $deploymentLabel
>
> [11:31:21][Step 3/3] + >~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   [11:31:21][Step 3/3]     + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set->AzureService], ComputeCloud
>
> [11:31:21][Step 3/3]    Exception
>
> [11:31:21][Step 3/3]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : >Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagemen
>
> [11:31:21][Step 3/3]    t.HostedServices.SetAzureServiceCommand

Can any one has idea whats going wrong here ?

Comment: I also facing same issue on azure automation and I am trying to create vm with ssh public key but getting same error on this command *Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName 'xxxxxxxx' -SubscriptionId   xx  -CurrentStorageAccountName 'xxxx' -Certificate $Certificate* , How to solve issue. plz

Comment: I know this question is quite old but in case it is still causing trouble / someone else has the same issue. I had the same problem when moving to a new publishsettings certificate. The machines where for some reason defaulting to old azure certificate accounts. To solve this run `Get-AzureAccount`. If there are accounts there associated with old / expired certificates run `Remove-AzureAccount <certificateThumbprint>`.

Answer (score 7):

I finally got the solution

The error message that I got was

> Set-AzureService : ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the
>   request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this >subscription.

It’s a bit misleading because as you can see in the code below (esp: last line), I did set the current storage but why did I get this message?

> [05:14:33][Step 3/3] Set-AzureService : ForbiddenError: The server failed to >authenticate the
>   [05:14:33][Step 3/3] request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is >associated with this
>   [05:14:33][Step 3/3] subscription.
>   [05:14:33][Step 3/3] At line:1 char:1
>   [05:14:33][Step 3/3] + Set-AzureService -ServiceName $service -Label >$deploymentLabel
>   [05:14:33][Step 3/3] + >~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   [05:14:33][Step 3/3] + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set->AzureService], ComputeCloud
>   [05:14:33][Step 3/3] Exception
>   [05:14:33][Step 3/3] + FullyQualifiedErrorId : >Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagemen
>   [05:14:33][Step 3/3] t.HostedServices.SetAzureServiceCommand

The script was working fine when run in VM Powershell but failed when run with Teamcity.

To resolve this I followed the following Steps :

Open Windows Powershell on VM

- Run "Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile". It will ask you to login to Azure
  and you will get the publish setting file for your Azure Subscription
  associated with your account.
- Then run "Add-AzureAccount", It will ask you to login and your
  account will be added to powershell. Login to Azure Portal
  (manage.windowsazure.com).
- Go to Settings => Management Certificates section. Get the ThumbPrint
  of the recently added PublishSettingCertificate.
- On Powershell run Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile "path of your
  publish setting file on VM"
- Run Add-AzureCertificate -serviceName "Your service Name"
  -certToDeploy (get-item cert:\CurrentUser\MY"Certificate ThumbPrint you got from Azure") Finally "Get-AzureSubscription", to see the
  subscriptions added on Powershell.

Hope this helps some one :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the user you used in PowerShell directly on the VM the same as the one configured for TeamCity?

I had the same error when I was trying to get the Azure subscriptions via PowerShell using Get-AzureSubscription in an Azure Runbook. It might be that our credential had some RBAC configuration issues.

In my case I created a new (organizational) account and used that instead, which solved my problem. Maybe worth trying?